# Xamarin Json deserealizacion

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

al hacer un request a mi Api desde mi aplicación, la Api me devuelve un JSON muy largo, del cual solo me interesan algunos datos , para procesar (deseralizar) mi petición, he creado una clase con ayuda de la siguiente pag http://json2csharp.com/
, que me ayuda creando la clase pertinente para mi json, lo que quiero es accesar a mis datos y ponerlos en un listview, pero creo que estoy haciendo algo mal. Sobre todo mi pregunta es, una vez desealizado, como llego a los objetos de **TABLE1** ???

**Método**

```js
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);


switch (response.StatusCode) {
  //200
  case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK):

    HttpContent content = response.Content;
    string xjson = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //string st_json = xjson.ToString();

    // 

    try {
      List < Table_Loc > loc_list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < List < Table_Loc >> (xjson);

      res_x.Text = xjson;
      /*
      mi sueño, mi epifanía sería algo asi ... creo??
      listloc es un listview
      ListoLoc.ItemsItemsSource =  List<Table_Loc> loc_list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Table_Loc>>(xjson);
      */
      
      
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      await DisplayAlert("", "" + ex.ToString(), "ok");
      return;
    }

    break;
```

**Json**

```js
{
    "DatosEnvio": null,
    "DatosEnvioJson": null,
    "DatosEnvioJsonDatos": null,
    "DatosEnvioJsonTitulos": null,
    "tabla": null,
    "tablas": {
        "Table1": [
            {
                "IdUsuario": 1,
                "Longitud": "-98.2491364",
                "Latitud": "19.0604784",
                "FechaAlta": "2018-02-22T11:58:33.7"
            }
        ]
    },
    "bandera": "0",
    "mensaje": "SE OBTUVIERON LOS DATOS DE MANERA CORRECTA"
}
```

**Clase**

```js
public class Table_Loc {
  public int IdUsuario {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string Longitud {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string Latitud {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public DateTime FechaAlta {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

public class Tablas {
  public List < Table_Loc > Table_Loc {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

public class Root {
  public object DatosEnvio {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public object DatosEnvioJson {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public object DatosEnvioJsonDatos {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public object DatosEnvioJsonTitulos {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public object tabla {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public Tablas tablas {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string bandera {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string mensaje {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para deserializar correctamente el  jsonresult que tienes, debes tener en cuenta la estructura con la cual la vas  hacer para ello una buena ayuda es la pagina de http://json2csharp.com/  que da correctamente el modelo que debes usar, pero  que por alguna razon cambias el nombre de la **Table1** por  **Table_Loc** lo cual ya de por si no te haría hacer la correcta Deserializacion.

Como primer paso debes hacerlo la deserializacion usando el objeto **RootObject** que te da como Model la pagina (Este objeto puede cambiarsele el nombre ya que no se usa como una lista interna de tu resultado) para este caso le cambie el nombre a **Root**.

```
// Models Generados
public class Table1
{
    public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
    public string Longitud { get; set; }
    public string Latitud { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaAlta { get; set; }
}

public class Tablas
{
    public List<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public object DatosEnvio { get; set; }
    public object DatosEnvioJson { get; set; }
    public object DatosEnvioJsonDatos { get; set; }
    public object DatosEnvioJsonTitulos { get; set; }
    public object tabla { get; set; }
    public Tablas tablas { get; set; }
    public string bandera { get; set; }
    public string mensaje { get; set; }
}
```

La logica que comentas en la funcion es la correcta solo que no debe hacerse usando la lista de **Table_loc** sino el **Root** de esta forma:

```
Root miobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(xjson);
```

Después de eso puedes acceder a las propiedades de la variable **miobject**. 
Quedaria la linea de try catch asi:

```
try  
{
  Root myobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(xjson);
  ListoLoc.ItemsItemsSource = myobject.tablas; //tablas es la lista de Table1 

} catch (Exception ex) {
  await DisplayAlert("", "" + ex.ToString(), "ok");
  return;
}
```

Pero la propiedad  **ItemsItemsSource**  no me aparece en la prueba que hice de un Listview si fueras  amable de brindarme mas información actualizaría la respuesta.

Comment: hahahahahaha es solo **ItemsSource** gracias estuvo incrible la solución, pero yo pusé **ListLoc.ItemsSource = myobject.tablas.Table1;** y listo :D